# Is subflow called from flow is part of same transaction?

Tags: visual-workflow, transaction, subflow

I have a sub-flow that is to be called from flow, Just want to know will the sub-flow be considered to be part of the same transaction as that of flow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sub-flow is part of the same transaction. The sub-flow is really an organizational encapsulation of logic to make flows easier to read and debug as well as promote reuse of common logic.  In the old old days of programming, the sub-flow is like a subroutine.

The only aspect of Flows that start new transactions are

- [Pause, Screen , or local action elements](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_transaction.htm&type=5)
- Asynchronous paths on record-triggered flows

Plus anything the flow does that starts asynchronous transactions like:

- Invocable apex that in turn does a @future, queueable, batchable, schedulable, or publishes a platform event
- Publish a platform event

Comment: All invocable apex is in a separate transaction from what I have seen. But then I was looking at this in the context of apex that published a platform event, so maybe not...?

Comment: @PhilW invocable apex executed from a flow action is in the same transaction based on my experience.  But you are making me question myself. :-)

Comment: Well, a publish after commit platform event requires the transaction to include at least one other DML operation. Our flow had one prior to the invocable apex call, but the platform event was never published, implying that the Apex called ran in a separate transaction. I probably need to re-test this.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/323560/platform-events-and-the-publish-after-commit-behaviour-why-do-events-not-pub

Comment: Thank you so much, Phil and Cropredy for your valuable feedback it resolved most of my issues and let me decide the workaround. Thank you so much guys.

Comment: and Phil Thanks for sharing the link, it actually solved another question coming in my mind

Comment: @PhilW - I just reverified that for record-triggered flows that have an apex action (invocable) - the invocable apex executes in the _same_ transaction as the "calling" flow.

Comment: That is very interesting. I wonder if something changed or if there is something special with platform events in invocable methods...? I will need to revisit for myself in my use case.

Comment: To be noted: new Transaction does not mean, that the new transaction got executet. If origin transaction runs into an unhandled exception also future Calls, batched or scheduled jobs are CANCELED, too!

The only exemption are platform Events which are defined as "publish immediatly". these events are published although the transaction rollbacks.